# Tabbed text file to MultiDimensional hash using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring about how I'd go about this for a part of my project. Basically I need to take a normal tabbed text file and convert it into a Multi Dimensional hash in Ruby so I can cycle through and detect which parts have children. An example of the file:

```
hello
    world
    how
are
    you
        today
```

Would become:

`{'hello' => ['world', 'how'], 'are' => {'you' => ['today']}}`

Comment: Is the leading whitespace actually tab characters or a given number of spaces?

Comment: It would preferably be tabs. Much like yaml, just not requiring a value to be assigned to the variables.

Comment: What do you mean "preferably"? If your input file is flexible like that then just use YAML.

Comment: But I don't need YAML. YAML requires a 'key: value' like syntax.

Comment: You have keys and values. Also the resulting "array" you have is not an array—it's a hash with incorrect square braces.

Comment: If you take a look at 'world', 'how' and 'today' they have no values.

Answer (score 2):

Since your input format is up to you, I really don't understand why you're not using YAML:

```
puts { 'hello' => ['world', 'how'], 'are' => { 'you' => ['today'] } }.to_yaml
```

yields:

```
---
hello:
- world
- how
are:
  you:
  - today
```

Calling [`YAML.load`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/YAML.html#M002015) with that string, of course, returns the original data structure. Contrary to what you believe, YAML does not require a "key value syntax".